# AXIS2/C and ONVIF

Tags: c++, wso2, onvif, axis2c

I'm trying to create the stub of the wsdl http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl using AXIS2/C (c++), using the following command:

> ./WSDL2CPP.sh -uri http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl

and I get the following answer:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2CPP.main(WSDL2CPP.java:19)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: **`No service was not found in the WSDL at http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl with targetnamespace http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl`**
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.populateAllServices(WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:115)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:147)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the [hack used on python-zeep](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/106#issuecomment-229768119), but it helps with axis2/c as well:

Add this to devicemgmt.wsdl, just before the close tag "</wsdl:definitions>":

```
<wsdl:service name="DeviceService">
             <wsdl:port name="DevicePort" binding="tds:DeviceBinding">
               <soap:address location="http://192.168.1.100/onvif/device_service"/>
             </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

However, I'm still having problems generating the code with any of the variable bindings ("XSD complexType with mix content not supported in ADB"). I had to disable it as follows:

```
./WSDL2C.sh -o ../axis2c-test/gen -d none -uri devicemgmt.wsdl
```

Answer (score 0):

This error normally coming because of the tool cannot find a service element in the WSDL. Because in WSDL definition it has to have a endpoint defined. Please check your WSDL whether it has a service element included or any other imported WSDL has the service element.

So basically to get rid of this you have to define a endpoint in this WSDL.